# OpenSearch Dashboard time field

Tags: fluentd, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have Fluentd + OpenSearch + OpenSearch Dashboard stack for working with logs. The problem is my time field in Opensearch Dashboard is string, so my filter by time doesn't work.

[image: OpenSearch Dashboard screen]

Any body knows what's wrong with my configuration?

Fluentd parser:

```xml
<source>
 @type tail
  path /opt/liferay/logs/*.json.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/test1_gpay.pos
  read_from_head true
  follow_inodes true
  refresh_interval 10
  tag gpay1
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_type string
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
    time_key time
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</source>
```

My log format is:

```json
{"time":"2023-02-07 14:00:00.039", "level":"DEBUG", "thread":"[liferay/scheduler_dispatch-3]", "logger":"[GeneralListener:82]", "message":"Found 0 tasks for launch."}
```

And what I have in OpenSearch Dashboard:

[image: screenshot]

I tried to use scripted fields in OpenSearch Dashboard, but my filter for time doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tag  "Scripted fields". [image]

In this tag, you can create a new custom field and convert your string  *2023-02-07 14:00:00.039*  to a new field with the field_type is Date so that you can use that field to filter.

For example, I saved date_time as string epoch time. Now I convert to type date below. Then I use that field for filter date time.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened when you first indexed your document and the dates were string. For future data, you can modify the index template mappings and specify a “date” mapping.

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/index-templates/